# Images in html content doesnt get rendered in outlook , image region goes blank

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, outlook, oracle-apex

i am trying to create HTML content using PLSQL and using this HTML in oracle apex page dynamic sql content .I am makingh this item copyable and while composing the email i copy this item and paste it in the outlook mail composer .it works fine for most of the cases but for few mails outlook doesnt render images in it , the image region goes blank .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When we embed an image in the html which we use as the email body for outlook and if the image source URL is greater than a limit probably 2000 characters , Outlook desktop app doesnt render the image , i believe this is a limitation with outlook .We dont have this issue when we use Outlook Web app for composing the mail as Outlook Web is able to handle the long URL .